# How to add SQL Server 2014 in Prerequisites for Setup Wizard project

Tags: sql-server

I created a program that needs a localDB and I have used SQL Server 2014. Now when I try to create the final executable file with a Setup Wizard project I can't set as a Prerequisite SQL Server 2014, I have only SQL Server 2012:

[image]

The problem is that I tried to install and use the program in a Windows 7 virtual machine and it does not work because I get the error that "The specified LocalDB instance does not exists" and in cmd I am able to create only v11 localDB instances.

How can I add SQL Server as a prerequisite in the list instead of SQL Server 2012?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it. There might be Some changes required to suit your purpose. Also locations could differ slightly based on your machine configuration. I had a 64bit Windows 10 and was doing it for Visual Studio 2015

1. Locate the SDK folder. For me it was (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\`)
2. Copy the folder names `SqlExpress2012` and name it `SqlExpress2014`
3. Open up `product.xml` and make some changes. Below is what I have after making changes

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.12.0">
     <RelatedProducts>
       <EitherProducts>
         <DependsOnProduct Code=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
         <DependsOnProduct Code=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
       </EitherProducts>
       <!-- Also depends on MSI4.5 or greater, which is included on all of the OS levels supported (see package.xml) -->
       <IncludesProduct Code="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.1.0" />
       <IncludesProduct Code="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.9.2" />
       <IncludesProduct Code="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.10.0" />
       <IncludesProduct Code="Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.10.5" />
       <IncludesProduct Code="Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.11.0" />
     </RelatedProducts>
     <PackageFiles>
       <PackageFile Name="SqlExpressChk.exe" />
     </PackageFiles>
   </Product>`
4. Download and copy the appropriate files in the folders designated for your specific languages (**en** in my case)
   You would need to copy eula and the two setup files (1 for 32 bit and other for 64 bit)
5. Once done, open `package.xml` file in the same folder and modify it to suit your needs. Below is what it looks like after modifications for me.

   ```
   <!-- Defines a new installation (x86) -->
   <Command PackageFile="SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE"
        Arguments='/q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck'
        EstimatedInstalledBytes="225000000"
        EstimatedInstallSeconds="420">
     <InstallConditions>
       <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="ValueNotExists" String="InvalidPlatformOS"/>
       <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.0.0" String="InvalidPlatformOS"/>
       <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.0.2" String="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack"/>
       <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionEqualTo" Value="6.1.0" String="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack"/>
       <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <FailIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="-1" String="InvalidUpgradeNotExpress"/>
       <FailIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="-2" String="InvalidUpgradeNotExpressCore"/>
       <FailIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="-3" String="InvalidUpgradeLanguage"/>
       <FailIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="-4" String="InvalidUpgradeWoW"/>
       <FailIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueLessThan" Value="-4" String="GeneralFailure"/>
       <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel"/>
       <BypassIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="1"/>
     </InstallConditions>
     <ExitCodes>
       <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
       <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0BC2 (1214,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067919934" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84C10BC2 (1217,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067723326" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0007 (1214,7) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922937" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4001F (1220,31) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529697" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0001 (1214,1)-->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922943" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000E (1220,14) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529714" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSLanguage"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000B (1220,11) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529717" Result="Fail" String="AnotherInstanceRunning"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01F8 (1214,504) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922440" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01FA (1214,506) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922438" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0202 (1214,514) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922430" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0203 (1214,515) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922429" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <ExitCode Value="216" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
     </ExitCodes>
   </Command>

   <!-- Defines an upgrade installation (x86) -->
   <Command PackageFile="SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE"
        Arguments="/q /hideconsole /action=Upgrade /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck"
        EstimatedInstalledBytes="225000000"
        EstimatedInstallSeconds="420">
     <InstallConditions>
       <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel"/>
       <BypassIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="2"/>
     </InstallConditions>
     <ExitCodes>
       <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
       <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0BC2 (1214,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067919934" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84C10BC2 (1217,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067723326" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0007 (1214,7) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922937" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4001F (1220,31) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529697" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0001 (1214,1)-->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922943" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000E (1220,14) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529714" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSLanguage"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000B (1220,11) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529717" Result="Fail" String="AnotherInstanceRunning"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01F8 (1214,504) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922440" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01FA (1214,506) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922438" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0202 (1214,514) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922430" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0203 (1214,515) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922429" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <ExitCode Value="216" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
     </ExitCodes>
   </Command>

   <!-- Defines a new installation (amd64) -->
   <Command PackageFile="SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE"
        Arguments='/q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck'
        EstimatedInstalledBytes="225000000"
        EstimatedInstallSeconds="420">
     <InstallConditions>
       <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64"/>
       <BypassIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="1"/>
     </InstallConditions>
     <ExitCodes>
       <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
       <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0BC2 (1214,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067919934" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84C10BC2 (1217,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067723326" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0007 (1214,7) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922937" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4001F (1220,31) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529697" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0001 (1214,1)-->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922943" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000E (1220,14) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529714" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSLanguage"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000B (1220,11) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529717" Result="Fail" String="AnotherInstanceRunning"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01F8 (1214,504) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922440" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01FA (1214,506) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922438" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0202 (1214,514) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922430" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0203 (1214,515) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922429" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <ExitCode Value="216" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
     </ExitCodes>
   </Command>

   <!-- Defines an upgrade installation (amd64) -->
   <Command PackageFile="SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE"
        Arguments="/q /hideconsole /action=Upgrade /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck"
        EstimatedInstalledBytes="225000000"
        EstimatedInstallSeconds="420">
     <InstallConditions>
       <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64"/>
       <BypassIf Property="SQLExpressChk" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="2"/>
     </InstallConditions>
     <ExitCodes>
       <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
       <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0BC2 (1214,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067919934" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84C10BC2 (1217,3010) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067723326" Result="FailReboot"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0007 (1214,7) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922937" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4001F (1220,31) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529697" Result="Fail" String="AdminRequired"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0001 (1214,1)-->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922943" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000E (1220,14) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529714" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformOSLanguage"/>
       <!-- 0x84C4000B (1220,11) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067529717" Result="Fail" String="AnotherInstanceRunning"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01F8 (1214,504) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922440" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE01FA (1214,506) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922438" Result="Fail" String="BetaComponentsFailure"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0202 (1214,514) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922430" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <!-- 0x84BE0203 (1214,515) -->
       <ExitCode Value="-2067922429" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <ExitCode Value="216" Result="Fail" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture"/>
       <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
     </ExitCodes>
   </Command>
   ```

   ```
   <Strings>
       <String Name="DisplayName">SQL Server 2014 Express</String>
       <String Name="Culture">en</String>
       <String Name="SqlExpr32Exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230852&amp;clcid=0x409</String>
       <String Name="SqlExpr64Exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=230853&amp;clcid=0x409</String>
       <String Name="AdminRequired">You do not have the permissions required to install SQL Server 2014 Express. Please contact your administrator.</String>
       <String Name="GeneralFailure">An error occurred attempting to install SQL Server 2014 Express.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidPlatformOS">The current operating system version does not support SQL Server 2014 Express.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidPlatformOSServicePack">The current operating system does not meet Service Pack level requirements for SQL Server 2014 Express. Install the most recent Service Pack from the Microsoft download center at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads before continuing setup.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidPlatformOSLanguage">The English version of SQL Server 2014 Express can only be installed on a Windows operating system of the same language.</String>
       <String Name="AnotherInstanceRunning">Another instance of setup is already running. The running instance must complete before this setup can proceed.</String>
       <String Name="BetaComponentsFailure">A beta version of the .NET Framework or SQL Server was detected on the computer. Uninstall any previous beta versions of SQL Server 2014 components, SQL Server Support Files, or .NET Framework before continuing.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidPlatformArchitecture">This version of SQL Server 2014 Express is not supported for the current processor architecture.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidUpgradeNotExpress">The instance of SQL Server named 'SQLEXPRESS' is a not an instance of SQL Server Express. It cannot be upgraded to SQL Server 2014 Express.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidUpgradeNotExpressCore">The instance of SQL Server Express named 'SQLEXPRESS' contains components that are not included in SQL Server 2014 Express. SQL Server 2014 Express cannot upgrade this instance. Please use SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services instead.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidUpgradeLanguage">The instance of SQL Server Express named 'SQLEXPRESS' is a different language version than this SQL Server 2014 Express. SQL Server 2014 Express cannot upgrade this instance.</String>
       <String Name="InvalidUpgradeWoW">SQL Server 2014 Express (x64) cannot upgrade the existing instance of SQL Server Express (x64 WoW) named 'SQLEXPRESS'. Uninstall this instance of SQL Server Express and retry installing SQL Server 2014 Express (x64).</String>
   </Strings>
   ```

Once done, restart visual Studio and you should now see SQL Server 2014 Express listed as well.